# How to create advanced rules with firewall-cmd?

Tags: iptables, firewall, firewalld

I want to create a rule using firewalld that uses criteria username or userID and maybe one other module criteria.

In iptables, I think you can do things like

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <UID> -j ACCEPT
```

(and you can add other -m modules or -p protocols to the same command)

But I read [`firewall-cmd` manpage](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora18/man1/firewall-cmd.1.html) and I cannot find how to make same kind of rule. Even "rich rules" don't seem to have this support. Do I have to use the "direct" feature? I can't quite understand its syntax. Especially it worries me that these returns nothing!

```
firewall-cmd --direct --get-chains ipv4 filter
firewall-cmd --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter OUTPUT
firewall-cmd --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter INPUT
```

Of course `iptables -L` shows I have those tables, chains and rules in them.

So how do I add a **permanent** rule with owner and maybe one more criteria using firewalld?

Comment: Yes, I would use a direct rule for this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but I don't know how. And note the direct command isn't even seeing the tables and chains!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add or even have custom direct chains (though you can if you want to get *really* complicated. Just add to your existing chains directly.

After IP version, table, chain and priority, you simply specify the relevant iptables options:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 \
        -m owner --uid-owner $UID -j ACCEPT
```

Underneath, at iptables, this will actually be added to a firewalld-managed chain named OUTPUT_direct, which is called from the OUTPUT chain.

Comment: I don't want to add special chains or tables. Note that the commands I listed are just trying to query the default tables and chains but they don't show *anything at all*. Why doesn't it list, e.g. the INPUT chain for the filter table? I'm concerned adding to tables and chains that it thinks don't exist will screw things up!!

Comment: Those are default chains and are never listed by those commands if they're empty. I know the above will work because I pulled it off one of my production systems. :)

Comment: REALLY? That's nuts! :) So if I add a rule like this to a default chain, I won't be able to query it back? Does that mean I won't be able to delete it? Frankly, this incomplete and screwy layer on top of iptables seems misleading and just as complicated as learning iptables in the first place. I will try your suggestion shortly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it's screwy. Firewalld still needs some work. But it's mostly usable. For the most part, if I have to add direct rules, I edit the XML directly. But you should see rules with `--get-rules` after you add them.

Comment: Oh that's a good tip. XML sounds like a less frustrating experience.

Comment: There's no documentation what the priority argument is. Is that same as the rule number in iptables (optional to iptables, apparently required by firewalld)?

Comment: No, it's a priority, and it is documented in the firewalld.direct man page.

Comment: Your suggestion worked and the rule is listed when using `--get-rules` but how in the world do you delete?!? `firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0` Simply returns with command usage info as if the args are wrong. What does it want, the whole rule again?

Comment: You write the entire rule again.

Comment: Yep, the whole exact rule must be repeated in order to delete. For example `firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m owner --uid-owner $UID -j ACCEPT`